# Is $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k(N-1)}{N}\right) =0$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a proof where I know a quantity vanishes. When I reduce the expression I obtain,
$$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k(N-1)}{N}\right)$$
for natural numbers $N$ and $k$ with $k<N$,
but it is not clear to me why this vanishes. I cannot find an example where it does not.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the facts that:

- $\sin$ is periodic, i.e., $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}: \sin(2\pi k + x) = \sin(x)$
- $\sin$ is odd, i.e., $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$.

So:

$$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k(N-1)}{N}\right)$$
$$= \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) + \sin\left(2\pi k - \frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)$$
$$= \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) + \sin\left(- \frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)$$
$$= \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)$$
$$= 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin \left( \frac{2 \pi k(N-1)}{N} \right) = \sin \left(2 \pi k - \frac{2 \pi k}{N} \right) = \sin \left( - \frac{2 \pi k}{N} \right) = -\sin \left( \frac{2 \pi k}{N} \right)$$
$$\therefore \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi k}{N} \right) + \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi k(N-1)}{N} \right) = 0$$
when $k \in \mathbb{Z}$